# Change Icon via JQuery with SlideDown and SlideUp

Tags: jquery

I want to change an icon so that it works with `slideDown` and `slideUp`.
The icon disappears with the slide effect, but appears without it.

Does anyone know where the mistake lies or if there is possibly another method to implement my plan? In the end, I want to make the icons of this form change just like the rest of the form:

https://kult13.de/contact

Current HTML Code:

```js
$("#recipient").on('hange', function() {
  let value = $("#recipient option:selected").val();
  if (value) {
    let target = $('#' + value);

    target.slideDown();
    target.siblings('.form-hide').slideUp();

    if (value === 'contact') {
      $("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").removeClass();
      }).slideDown("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").addClass("fas fa-comments fa-fw");
      });
    } else if (value === 'webmaster') {
      $("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").removeClass();
      }).slideDown("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").addClass("fas fa-code fa-fw");
      });
    } else if (value === 'uploader') {
      $("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").removeClass();
      }).slideDown("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").addClass("fas fa-file-upload fa-fw");
      });
    } else if (value === 'support') {
      $("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").removeClass();
      }).slideDown("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").addClass("fas fa-medkit fa-fw");
      });
    } else if (value === 'issues') {
      $("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").removeClass();
      }).slideDown("fast", function() {
        $("#recipient-icon").addClass("fas fa-bug fa-fw");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mx-500">
  <h1 class="sr-only">Kontakt</h1>
  <div class="card-header">
    <label for="recipient" class="sr-only">Empfänger</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 46px;">
          <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-fw" id="recipient-icon"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" name="recipient" id="recipient" size="1" required>
        <option class="d-none" value="">Empfänger wählen</option>
        <option value="contact" {{contact}}>Allgemeine Kontaktanfrage</option>
        <option value="webmaster" {{webmaster}}>Kontakt mit dem Webmaster</option>
        <option value="uploader" {{uploader}}>Eigene Patches anbieten</option>
        <option value="support">Support</option>
        <option value="issues">Homepage Issue- &amp; Wishes-Tracker</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form action="{{REQUEST_URI}}" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="contact">
    <!--
    contact Form
    -->
  </form>
  <form action="{{REQUEST_URI}}" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="webmaster">
    <!--
    webmaster Form
    -->
  </form>
  <form action="{{REQUEST_URI}}" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="uploader">
    <!--
    uploader Form
    -->
  </form>
  <div class="card-body form-hide d-none text-center" id="issues">
    <!--
    issues Form
    -->
  </div>
  <div class="card-body form-hide d-none text-center" id="support">
    <!--
    support Form
    -->
  </div>
```

---

Now everything is as it should be, I had "keyup change" instead of just "change" as event, so of course the animation was doubled when you changed with the arrow keys.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add your HTML code also, so it would be good to understand.

Comment: I've edit the post....

Comment: In your given link icon is changing, so what is issue there?

Comment: If you change with the arrow keys, the new icon is double pushed up and the slide to the new icon is no slide.

Comment: Only use change event and remove keyup event.It double pushed because both events fire.why you have put keyup event, change event work in arrow key also.

Comment: If you click the `[<>]` snippet editor, you can create a [mcve]. JS and rendered HTML

Comment: I made a snipppet - I had to add a } before the last })

Comment: Yes, the event was the problem. With "Change" it works as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Just add classes before slideDown

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/asokr/pen/NZLBQd)

```
$("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast",function(){
  $("#recipient-icon").removeClass().addClass("fas fa-bug fa-fw");
});
$("#recipient-icon").slideDown("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is waiting until the element is finished sliding down before changing the icon. Since all classes are removed at the end of sliding up, no icon is visible when it slides back down. Then the icon appears when the classes are added again, after sliding down.

> .slideDown( [duration ] [, complete ] )

Try changing the icon after the element finishes sliding up.
For example:

```
$("#recipient-icon").slideUp("fast", function() {
  $(this).removeClass().addClass("fas fa-comments fa-fw");
}).slideDown("fast");
```

---

For efficiency, I recommend using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to define the icon for each `<option>`.
That allows you to remove much of the duplicated code (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

For example:

```
<option value="contact" data-icon="comments">Allgemeine Kontaktanfrage</option>
```

```
let icon = $(':selected', $recipientSelect).data('icon');
$recipientIcon.removeClass().addClass("fas fa-" + icon + " fa-fw");
```

Other suggestions:

- Remove the `keyup` event, since `change` is sufficient.
- Use [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to prevent queuing the jQuery animations.

Here's a working demonstration:

```js
let $recipientSelect = $('#recipient');
let $recipientIcon = $('#recipient-icon');

$recipientSelect.on('change', function() {

  let value = $recipientSelect.val();
  let icon = $(':selected', $recipientSelect).data('icon');

  if (value) {
    let $target = $('#' + value);
    $target.slideDown();
    $target.siblings('.form-hide').slideUp();
  }

  if (icon) {
    $recipientIcon.stop(true, true).slideUp("fast", function() {
      $recipientIcon.removeClass().addClass("fas fa-" + icon + " fa-fw");
    }).slideDown("fast");
  }

});
```

```css
.form-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-header">
  <label for="recipient" class="sr-only">Empfänger</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-fw" id="recipient-icon"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" name="recipient" id="recipient" size="1" required>
      <option class="d-none" value="">Empfänger wählen</option>
      <option value="contact" data-icon="comments">Allgemeine Kontaktanfrage</option>
      <option value="webmaster" data-icon="code">Kontakt mit dem Webmaster</option>
      <option value="uploader" data-icon="file-upload">Eigene Patches anbieten</option>
      <option value="support" data-icon="medkit">Support</option>
      <option value="issues" data-icon="bug">Homepage Issue- &amp; Wishes-Tracker</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="contact">
  contact Form
</form>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="webmaster">
  webmaster Form
</form>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-hide d-none" id="uploader">
  uploader Form
</form>
<div class="card-body form-hide d-none text-center" id="issues">
  issues Form
</div>
<div class="card-body form-hide d-none text-center" id="support">
  support Form
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('.slide-content').hide();
  $('.slide-header').click(function() {       
    $('.slide-content').slideToggle(460);  
    if($('.slide-header i').hasClass('fa fa-minus')){
      $('.slide-header i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-plus');
    } else {
      $('.slide-header i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-minus');
    }
  })
```

```css
.slideDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.slide-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.slide-header>a {  
  flex:0.95;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #000;
}

.slide-content {
  padding: 5px 10px;  
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container my-5 slideDiv">
    <div class="slide-header">
      <a href="#FIXME" class="d-block">
        slideMe
      </a>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-content">
      <p>Eiusmod nostrud voluptate ex id consectetur deserunt. Et occaecat cupidatat quis ad sit sint. Quis enim velit esse consequat occaecat labore nostrud laboris anim nulla. Aliquip consequat id Lorem consequat esse non irure deserunt officia officia ad. Est voluptate eiusmod cupidatat elit mollit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```